# Im getting an exception for the process of sending mail from the spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sendemail.sendsemail.service.MailServiceImpl cannot be cast to class com.sendemail.sendsemail.service.MailService (com.sendemail.sendsemail.service.MailServiceImpl and com.sendemail.sendsemail.service.MailService are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @1132972)
    at com.sendemail.sendsemail.SendsemailApplication.main(SendsemailApplication.java:23)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: *java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sendemail.sendsemail.service.MailServiceImpl cannot be cast to class com.sendemail.sendsemail.service.MailService*

Comment: Please provide more detail on this,it seems from error that it is modular dependency error.

Comment: Please provide some code snippets of MailService, MailServiceImpl and the code where you are autowiring MailService etc.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ClassCastException: class <Class_Name> cannot be cast to class <Class_Name> (<Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader <Class_Name> is in unnamed module of loader 'app')`
This is related to the spring dev tools package. Try removing the package if it is not required.